# change the copied text by Clipboard.js

Tags: javascript, clipboard, zeroclipboard, clipboard.js

I'd like to parse the text copied by `Clipboard.js` and set it again to the Clipboard.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function addTableLines(originaltext) {
        result = '';
        var lines = originaltext.split('\n');
        console.log(lines);
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            var str = lines[i];
            console.log(str);
            var replaced = str.split(' ').join(' | ');
            replaced = replaced + '<br> ------- <br>';
            result += replaced;
        }
        return result;
    }

    new Clipboard('.clipboard-btn', {
        text: function (trigger) {
            var originaltext = $(trigger).next("orders-tbl").text();
            console.log(originaltext); // is empty
            return addTableLines(originaltext);
        }
    });
});
```

The `originaltext` is always empty, what's wrong with my implementation ?

Update, solution was:

```
  var originaltext = $(trigger).next('table').closest("#orders-tbl").text();
```

Comment: Try replacing `.next("orders-tbl")` with .next(".orders-tbl") or .next("#orders-tbl"), depends on youtr markup, would be great if you post that as well.